# Variable access in another class

Tags: java, oop

I have a variable in x class .And I have another class called "Y" to access the variable. Will it change the value in X class, if the value is incremented in Y class?

Comment: Hello. Can we see some of your code? How are you implementing `x` and `Y` class?

Comment: It depends on how you are incrementing the value in your class `x`. Is it private and returned by an getter, then probably no, do you access it directly because it´s inside the scope of visibily for class `Y`, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java uses pass by value but we can achieve what you are asking for by passing an object as an argument to a method like this:

```
public class ClassX {

public int classId;

public ClassX(int id) {
    this.classId = id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    classId = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return classId;
}
}


public class ClassY {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassX cx = new ClassX(100);
    ClassY cy = new ClassY();

    System.out.println("classId:"+cx.classId);
    cy.modifyId(cx); // an object is passed as argument to a method
    System.out.println("classId:"+cx.classId);

}

public void modifyId(ClassX classx) {
    classx.setId(220);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have it defined like

```
public int anInteger = 4;
```

Then yes, it would change.

These are the sorts of things best learned from experimentation, try various ways of structuring the classes, declaring the variable, and accessing it. See what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All you need is to pass a reference to it to the other class.